# What is the sum of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find the sum of $$\sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{(3n)}{4^n}(-1)^n$$
So far I've tried finding the nth partial sum and finding the sum through the geometric series equation k/(1-r) to no avail.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\dfrac1{(1-x)^2}$$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you! You are a lifesaver. I didn't notice that but I'll always keep this in mind now.